How to get httprequest result from the Xslist with cookie which change frequently by GM_xmlhttpRequest
I want to get the Info from the Xslist search result, but it seems to be only a request with the cookie
I use the GM_xmlhttpRequest in Tampermonkey with cookies, but the Xslist site cookie changes frequently
How to get HTTPrequest result from the Xslist with cookie
    let cookies = '...'
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'https://xslist.org/search?query=%E7%AF%A0%E5%AE%AE%E8%8A%B1%E9%9F%B3&lg=zh',
         anonymous: true,
         cookie: cookies;
         onload: function (result) {
             // xhrResult = result.status;
             let domNewx = new DOMParser().parseFromString(result.responseText, 'text/html');
             console.log(domNewx)
         }
     });

Open the Xslist directly usually shows a real person verify in the page

